# Crystal Reports - Is it possible to pass an operator to a report through a parameter?

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, operator-keyword

Bit of a puzzle I can't seem to find a solution for.
I've been playing with parameters in Crystal Reports 2011(also in v10 too) and wondered if it was possible to pass an operator to a report via a parameter.

E.g

I've created a report that shows counts of account numbers in their respective groups.

> GroupName.....Count
>
> GroupA................5
>
> GroupB...............10
>
> GroupC...............20

I have a parameter called 'Val' that relates to the counts, and one called 'Operator' that contains the different operators (>,<,=,etc)

At runtime I want the user to select the operator and value to narrow down their results but I can't create a selection criteria that says:

```
DistinctCount ({customers.account} {customers.type){?operator}{?val}
```

so in theory, the user could be entering the following (via the parameters):

```
DistinctCount ({customers.account} >= 10
```

Does anyone out there have any ideas how to accomplish this? 
Also, if there's any info you need that I haven't supplied, just give me a shout.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only do this through a long select record formula, something like:

```
Select Case {@Operator}

Case "=" :
    (If (DistinctCount ({customers.account} = 10)) then true else false)
Case ">" :
    (If (DistinctCount ({customers.account} > 10)) then true else false)
Case "<" : 
    (If (DistinctCount ({customers.account} < 10)) then true else false)
Case ">=" :
    (If (DistinctCount ({customers.account} >= 10)) then true else false)
Case "<=" :
    (If (DistinctCount ({customers.account} <= 10)) then true else false)
Default : false
```